# Simple way to add/delete children objects by name (w/o id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Promotion has_many promotion_keywords like this:

```
class Promotion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :promotion_keywords, dependent: :destroy
end

class PromotionKeyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :promotion
end
```

On UI keywords displayed in textarea, line per keyword - thus no id present.
User can create/update promotion with keywords - just editing keywords textarea.
Because there is no way getting id from text area - update of keyword is meaningless, just delete and create.

Please advise is there any way to handle this w/o manually promotion_keywords collection manipulation?

For instance, 
user created promotion with name Promo1 and keywords [keyword1, keyword2, keyword3]. 
user edited promotion and keywords become [keyword1, keyword4, keyword5].
So, keyword2, keyword3 should be deleted and keyword4, keyword5 added.

Please remember that keywords are just lines in textarea.

UPD: I know that i can PromotionKeyword.find_by_name and add index to make as fast as by id.
My question is: are there any elegant ways to handle this update w/o manually manipulate collection. Maybe some options on has_may or nested_attributes_for reject?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you displaying the keywords in a textarea? Why dont you use [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-fields_for) to display/edit the keywords?

Comment: Do you think having bunch on inputs - makes it easier for user to manage them? It also should be separate method for deletion, right?

Comment: [Building complex forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) from the Guides provides some more info on the `fields_for` approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came with this code:

```
persisted_keywords = promotion_keywords.map(&:keyword)
updated_keywords = value.split(/\r?\n/)

(updated_keywords - persisted_keywords).each do |keyword|
  promotion_keywords.build keyword:keyword
end

(persisted_keywords - updated_keywords).each do |keyword|
  deleted =  promotion_keywords.find_by(keyword:keyword)
  promotion_keywords.delete deleted
end
```

And all keywords modified when self.save method called. I just wanted to ask if there any built in methods to make. But looks like no.

Answer (score 0):

You could just find the PromotionKeyword by the string instead of the id.

```
PromotionKeyword.find_by_word('your_keyword')
```

Or:

```
@promotion.promotion_keyword.find_by_word('your_keyword')
```

It might be a little bit slower than finding by id, but should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
PromotionKeyword.find_by_word('keyword').destroy
```

It's a little unclear to me what is happening in your UI, so I may be off for some odd reason.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, you want to remove a keyword from a promotion if it has been removed from the textarea?

```
promotion.promotion_keyword.where('name not in (?)', ['keyword 1', 'keyword 2']).destroy_all
```

To find new Keywords:

```
['keyword 1', 'keyword 2'].delete_if{ |s| promotion.promotion_keyword.find_by_word.(s) }
```

Then you could do for example:

```
['keyword 1', 'keyword 2'].delete_if{ |s| promotion.promotion_keyword.find_by_word(s) }.each do |kw|
    promotion.build_promotion_keyword(:name => kw)
end
```

Comment: and add added :) let me update question to make it more clear